# Строительство по квадратным полям

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть идея для создании игры, но прежде чем начать, хотелось бы узнать как строить объекты (основа их квадратной формы) на карте при том, что территория **НЕ ровная** ! Обычно такой вид "строительства объектов" используется в стратегиях.

Пример строительства, о котором я говорю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если речь идет именно о размещении 3d объекта на поверхность то можно использовать рейкасты пускаемые сверху к поверхности для определения нужной высоты и угла помещаемого объекта.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал **конкретную проблему** с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:

1. Разрешать ставить здания только на идеально ровной земле (и соответственно создавать карты с такими областями).
2. Проверять и выравнивать местность под планируемым зданием.
3. Разрешать ставить здания боле-менее ровной земле. У самих зданий делать продолжение фундамента ниже уровня земли.

Как ставить здания по фиксированым координатам?

При размещении здания, всегда округляйте его положение до ближайшего шага сетки. Например при сетке `0.4` и курсоре `12.37 / 11.42` положение будет:

```
Round(12.37 / 0.4) * 0.4 = 12.4
Round(11.42 / 0.4) * 0.4 = 11.2
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы при строительстве террейн можете немного деформировать.
2. Можно оставить как есть. Во многих играх такими вещами не парятся, там здания могут парить в воздухе. Просто стараются сделать террейн более-менее плоским. Или, по крайней мере, если там горы/впадины, то делать сам наклон плоским, тогда здание можно просто наклонить.

Comment: а как строить по "невиденным клеткам"? Если приглядеться на фотографии, то здания построены "вряд". Есть ли видео или ресурсы, где рассказно как это делается?

Comment: @Antonio112009 вот курс по RTS на Unity https://www.lynda.com/Unity-tutorials/Unity-5-Build-Real-time-Strategy-Game/427923-2.html

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку